# Detect Backspace in VimL

Tags: vim

I'm attempting to detect whenever backspace is hit when typing in a specific scenario in Vim. I'm using getchar() to grab general characters from user input. Ideally, I'd like to detect the backspace keystroke in this manner. I was thinking of using stty somehow, but I'm not certain as of yet. Any suggestions?

Comment: What are you trying to do? (as in what sequence). There might be a better way to do what you are trying to do. Also it might be a good idea to post what code you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using getchar you can check whether user typed backspace by using

```
let char=getchar()
if char is# "\<BS>"
    …
endif
```

. This assumes vim is configured properly (only terminal vim, gvim does not have this problem). Most of the time it is, but sometimes in place of fixing terminfo or, more likely, using `set <BS>={<C-v><BS>}`, users just map characters produced when pressing `<BS>`. This can’t be helped.

Comment: Excellent, this snippet and your explanation helped rectify the issue.